# Flexslider <li> height's equal the tallest <li> on a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am trying to figure out an issue with Flexslider that only appears when I test it on an mobile browser such as Safari Mobile.

All of the <li> containers are the same height as the tallest <li>, even when there is not enough content to justify making them equal heights.

I am not sure how to grab a screen shot of this since it works fine on a desktop browser but not on mobile browsers.  Here's a fiddle that shows it working as I would expect when I view it on my desktop browser, the container's height resizes depending on the ammount of content.

http://jsfiddle.net/CsCyh/

Here is the hml:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
      <h2><a href"#">First Link Here</a></h2>
      <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Another Link Here</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
      <h2><a href"#">Second Link Here</a></h2>
      <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>      
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
     <h2><a href"#">Third Link Here</a></h2>
     <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>     
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS for flexslider:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the site?

Comment: I don't unfortunately.  jsFiddle is the best option that I can think of.  Is there a useful source for testing mobile browser behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I ran into this issue awhile ago. I hope this helps!

```
var evenSliderHeight = function(slideContainer, slideItem) {
  var slider_height = 0;
  var $slider_slide = $(slideContainer).find(slideItem);
  $slider_slide.each(function() {
    var __height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    if ( slider_height < __height ) {
       slider_height = __height;
    }
  });
  $slider_slide.css('min-height', slider_height);
};
evenSliderHeight('.flexslider-container', '.slide');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  after: function(slider){
    currHeight = $('.flexslider').find('.slides > li').eq(slider.currentSlide).outerHeight(true);
    $('.flexslider').height(currHeight);
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/CsCyh/14/

---

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still has this issue in 2019/2020, please have a look at the new property called "smoothHeight" at the [Flexslider docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider#readme)

I fixed my issue by setting "smoothHeight" to true.

```
$('.sliders').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    smoothHeight: true,
    controlNav: false,
    customDirectionNav: $('.js-slider-control button'),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS only solution. This is tested for the `animation: "slide"` property:

```
.flexslider .flex-viewport { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.flexslider .flex-viewport > ul { display: flex; }
.flexslider .flex-viewport > ul > li { display: flex !important; }
```

The `!important` overrides the `display:block;` property that flexslider generates as inline style. Now all panels share an equal height, based on the highest slide.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the script that calls the slider.

```
animateHeight: false,
```

eg.:

```
$(window).load(function(){ if ( $('#content-slider-wrap').length == 0 ) return false
    $('#content-slider-wrap').flexslider({
        animation:"fade",
        slideshow: true,
        directionNav: true,
        animateHeight: false,
        controlNav:false ,
........... etc etc
```