# 100% height slides on FlexSlider

Tags: css, height, flexslider

I'm trying to create a responsive slider with FlexSlider. My goal is to have all slides with the maximum height, equal to `.flexslider` 100% height.

The following snippet shows my issue: I would like all slides (both red and green) to have the maximum height, covering container height (independently from their content). I've tryed to set `height:100%;` but it doesn't work. What can I do?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/29X4C/)

Comment: Please see given answer, I have done with the help of JQuery but I think this will work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flexslider <li> height's equal the tallest <li> on a mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752070/flexslider-li-heights-equal-the-tallest-li-on-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: You don't want solution in JQuery?

Comment: I would prefer pure CSS, but if jQuery is the only way, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please apply below given JS code

```
 function setEqualHeight(selector) {
        var heights = new Array();

        $(selector).each(function() {

            $(this).css('min-height', '0');
            $(this).css('max-height', 'none');
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');

            heights.push($(this).height());
        });

        var max = Math.max.apply( Math, heights );
    $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).css('height', max + 'px');
        }); 
    }


        setEqualHeight('.slides li');

        $(window).resize(function() {

            setTimeout(function() {
                setEqualHeight('.slides li');
            }, 120);
        });

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
});
```

See [Updated Demo for Window Resize](http://jsfiddle.net/29X4C/8/)

Comment: This solution goes in the right way. I would like to extend it in case of window resize. I've added `$(window).resize(function () { setHeight($('.slides li')); });` in your snippet, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let me try to do this

Comment: function is working fine on resize you can check after applying al;ert in setheight function but one thing that how it will work content is same on resize as well then why you want to update the height.

Comment: If you reduce "Result" window width in your snippet, you may see that part of green content is hidden (and this is not correct). This is why I must update height on each window resize.

Comment: Yes got it I am working on this and let you know in 10 min max

Comment: I have updated code now it's working on window resize as well

Comment: Right right right... Accepted (and +1 for diligence!)

Answer (score 0):

Add this after default theme:

```
html {height: 100%}
body {height: 100%; margin: 0;}
.flex-viewport, .flexslider, .slides {height: 100%;margin: 0;border: none;border-radius: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {height: 100%;}
.flex-control-nav {bottom: 10px}
```

Soon i update with a fix for direction nav buttons overflow

Comment: It's almost there, @BrainStack. But my goal is to set all slide heights equal to the maximum slide height (in my case I would keep green slide height as is, and set red slide height equal to green height). In your case, all slides have html height and this may show extra background or hide content depending on browser window height.

Answer (score 0):

height:100% will not work because  it has no parent with some fix height. so the Red content is setting it's height according to it's content. 
In this case you can set some **min-height** in **#Red class**. it'll solve your problem.

```
#red {
background:red;
min-height:160px;
```

}

Comment: Hi @user3584501. Thanks for the help, but I think unfortunately it's not very flexible. Since slider must be responsive, content scrolls depending on window width and slide height may exceed 160px or cause extra background to be shown. My goal is to set all slides to the maximum height (in this case green height), which is the flexslider height too and cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to bodge together a CSS-only solution using display:flex;. This particular flexslider is 100% of the viewport width so I was able to use 100vw for the flexbasis/width of each slide.

```
ul.slides {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
}
```

Edit: I tried it on a non-100vw flexslider on another site and just adding `ul.slides { display: flex; }` may be enough for most usage.

Here's a Fiddle fork: http://jsfiddle.net/jokptLyh/